# Doubt about "と" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

i was reading a news and I saw that sentence: 警察は誰かが女の子を殺したあと、線路に置いた**と**考えて調べていました。

I can understand the most part of the words, just that "と", in "線路に置いた**と**考えて調べていました", is not understandable for me.

Can someone help me? :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

> 警察は**誰かが女の子を殺したあと、線路に置いた**と考えて調べていました。

rather than

> 警察は誰かが女の子を殺したあと、**線路に置いた**と考えて調べていました。

The と here indicates a quote.

Comment: Hm, I see. if it's not uncomfortable, how do you would translate it?  Just want check if I understood it right.

Comment: @Nome Aleatório I translated it as "The police were looking into the case as they thought that someone might have put the girl on a railway track after killing her."